# Odoo - Change Odoo Default Menu Item View

Tags: menu, odoo

When I follow some tutorials, the menu items are not the same as my default menu Items. I want to change the menu item from this

[image]

to something like this

[image]

How I can change that view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into [the OCA modules/extensions for web client](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/14.0) and especially for module `web_responsive`.

It will add such a menu and some other nice features, known from the enterprise web client.